# How does mobile Safari decide to sleep tabs?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

I have been working on a web application that relies on page auto-refresh. It works as I expected in desktop Safari, which is refreshing in the background even if it is not the primary tab. So long as Safari is open, that is.

On iOS, however, I've seen inconsistent behavior. It doesn't refresh if Safari is not open, but does still refresh if the tab is in the background. Again, this is what I expected.

However, it seems like Safari occasionally sleeps the tab, then reloads it when it's visited again. I'm not that surprised to see it, but I can't figure out the logic. There doesn't appear to be a timeout time that is consistent, so I'm assuming there is some other component at play. But I have no idea what it is.

Anyone know know this work? I had assumed it was documented somewhere, but I've not been able to find it.

Thanks!

Comment: IIRC, part of the equation is memory pressure; it'll suspend tabs if apps need more RAM for other purposes. This might explain the inconsistency.